Makefile to build one target from each individual source file
For each source file (C and C++ in this case) in a directory I need a generic rule that will compile the source file into a binary whose name is the basename of the sourcefile with the architecture appended.
My makefile is:
CC = gcc
CPP = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c89 -std=c99 -fpermissive
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++17 -fpermissive
BINDIR = ./bin

LIBS = -lm
ARCH = $(shell uname -m)

# Populate two variables with the source files
SRCS=$(wildcard *.c) 
CPP_SRCS=$(wildcard *.cpp)

# Create a list of the target files for the .C sources
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c, $(BINDIR)/%-$(ARCH), $(SRCS))
# Add a list of the target files for the .cpp sources
OBJS += $(patsubst %.cpp, $(BINDIR)/%-$(ARCH), $(CPP_SRCS))

all: $(OBJS)

# Rule to compile C++ sources into the appropriately named target
$(BINDIR)/% : %.cpp Makefile
    $(CPP) -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS)

# Rule to compile C sources into the appropriately named target
$(BINDIR)/% : %.c Makefile
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

This results in an error: make: *** No rule to make target `bin/file1-arm64', needed by `all'.  Stop.

This rule:
$(BINDIR)/% : %.cpp Makefile

tells make, "if you want to build a target that matches the pattern ./bin/% you can do it from a file %.cpp and Makefile".  Make wants to build a target ./bin/file1-arm64 and that matches the pattern with the stem % matching file1-arm64, so then make looks to see if the file %.cpp or file1-arm64.cpp exists or can be built.  It cannot be.  Ditto for file1-arm64.c.  So make gives an error.
You need:
$(BINDIR)/%-$(ARCH) : %.cpp Makefile

and:
$(BINDIR)/%-$(ARCH) : %.c Makefile

so that the stem (%) matches only the filename, without the architecture.
BTW you should really consider using := instead of =, especially when using $(shell ...).

Thank you. For the answer. For explaining the answer. And for the guidance on best practices. Very much appreciated!
